# How to use SSO, in asp net core for web page login?

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, single-sign-on

I have a web project. Previously, you could login with username and password from the normal login screen. However, my boss asked me to use SSO. The user should be able to login to my website with windows user information. I have no idea how to use it. Can anyone tell and send sample code?

Comment: Is this an `intranet` site?

Comment: yes an intranet site

Comment: Are you just trying to use `Windows Authentication`? If so, you can read these articles: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) and (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/)

Comment: thank you. I tried this myself but it didn't work. I will try again by following the article.

Comment: Do you have access to the server which hosts the application? Is the app running in IIS on the server?